# can record unc connection?

Tags: c#, unc, auditing

The Pc I use have an UNC file. I'm in a Network with other people.
Every other can open the file by tipping in the adress line \\file.

Know I want to write a c# programm in Vs2010 which watch over the file I use Win7 32bit. If any one Open the file the programm shall write in a Logfile that someone has open my file.

I tried to use the FileSystemWatcher but this only look for changes/saves/cration but not for Opening.

I read somthing about "auditing" and that I'm be able to do that(watch over my unc file) with this(auditing).But i tried to find out how to use auditing in c# but i found not much.

.

So my Questions:

Is it possible to do what i want with "auditing" ?

Did someone worked with auditing in c# befor or has anyone a link or somtihng to show me how it works in c#?

mfg Sam

Sry for bad english

Comment: Is this what you need: [How to audit user access of files, folders, and printers in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [unc monitor with C #](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019251/unc-monitor-with-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the [Audit Object Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776774%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

The steps you have to follow:

1. Enable the ***Audit object access*** in the ***Local Computer Policy***.
2. Enable auditing for the object you want to follow.
3. From your application, use the [EventLog.EntryWritten Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten.aspx) to detect the file opening event

Here's a simplistic sample usage, but you'll have to dig in the documentation in order to capture and log as you need to:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        EventLog myNewLog = new EventLog("Security", ".", "Microsoft Windows security");

        myNewLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(MyOnEntryWritten);
        myNewLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static async void MyOnEntryWritten(object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (e.Entry.InstanceId == 4656 || e.Entry.InstanceId == 4663)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Entry.Message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```