# Who Change the file?

Tags: c#, monitoring, filesystemwatcher

I´m writing a C# Program which record all changes in a UNC Path.
I use the File-System-Watcher in c# to record all changes in my file \D/X/Y(UNC path).

It works very good but now my question: how is it possible to record the Client which change/delete etc. the file ?

EDIT: The UNC Path will be seen in the whole network and I want to record which user change/delete etc a file in the UNC Path (Every one in the network can change the files). Each edit will be saved in real time in a .txt file. So that i can see :
who:PC2 what:change file:X
who:PC1 what:delet file:Y

Comment: Is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024211/can-record-unc-connection

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to get the credentials of the user that is logged in

```
string currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

If you put this wherever the code is for the file change/deletion is, this should work.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290694/how-do-you-monitor-file-access-and-changes-on-a-file-server-by-user-name)

You basically need to create an auditing process for this, I'm not aware there is a built in way to find information such as who last changed a file.

Comment: This is assuming that the logged in user is the only person who can modify the file.

Comment: But with this im only be able to record which user un my PC change a file in the unc path ?
i updatet my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "who" is claiming or modifying a file. As far as I am aware, you can view properties of a file (if you have permissions to view the permissions), the current user (see Jacooobley's answer), and the process that is locking the file.

I don't believe you can see the user who has last effected the file.

Comment: i updated my question. Couse im not the only one who can change