# How can i check if the file size is larger then it was in the beginning?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timerCount += 1;
            TimerCount.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timerCount).ToString();
            TimerCount.Visible = true;
            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(contentDirectory, "msinfo.nfo")))
            {
                string fileName = Path.Combine(contentDirectory, "msinfo.nfo");
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
                long s1 = f.Length;
                if (f.Length > s1)
                {
                    timer2.Enabled = false;
                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Once the file is exist its about 1.5mb size
but after some minutes the file is updating to almost 23mb.
So i want to check that if the file is larger then what it was before stop timer2 and start timer1.

But this line: if (f.Length > s1) not logical since im doing all the time long s1 = f.Length;

How can i check if the file is larger then what it was ?

Comment: Maybe there is another way to do it. The problem is that the file exist but then its updating with a program in the background after few minutes . My program is using backgroundworker but the problem is that its not detecting the background program that keep working (msinfo32.exe) and that updating the file after some minutes.

Comment: Check out this approach: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15024737/674700](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15024737/674700).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on a global variable (like the one you are using for `contentDirectory`) storing the last observed size. Sample code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    long timerCount = 0;
    string contentDirectory = "my directory";
    long lastSize = 0;
    double biggerThanRatio = 1.25;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerCount += 1;
        TimerCount.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timerCount).ToString();
        TimerCount.Visible = true;
        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(contentDirectory, "msinfo.nfo")))
        {
            string fileName = Path.Combine(contentDirectory, "msinfo.nfo");
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
            if (f.Length >= biggerThanRatio * lastSize && lastSize > 0)
            {
                timer2.Enabled = false;
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }

            lastSize = f.Length;
        }
    }
}
```